# how to export html table to excel using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am making one page and it displays more than 25K record without paging.
When I am exporting it to excel using following code of jquery,

it gives me error of page crash.

> window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent('' + $('.grid-     view').html() + '

*It is working for small amount of record but when record cross to 1500*, it starts  crashing browser page.

Please help me to solve out this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't show 25,000 records on one page it is a nightmare - also think about users who won't have as powerful machines as you - their browser will just crash.

Comment: @Chirag   Did you find any solution for your problem, bcz am also facing same problem

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe download as an attachment instead of displaying in the browser.

Comment: code is already downloading the excel file. but it is crash in between of export button click and excel downloading.